# Finding average of variable in objects python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I iterate over a group of objects to find their mean in the most efficent way? This uses just one loop (except perhaps loops in Numpy) but I was wondering whether there was a better way. At the moment, I am doing this:

```
scores = []
ratings= []
negative_scores = []
positive_scores = []

for t in text_collection:
 scores.append(t.score)
 ratings.append(t.rating)
 if t.score < 0:
    negative_scores.append(t.score)
 elif t.score > 0:
    positive_scores.append(t.score)

print "average score:", numpy.mean(scores)
print "average rating:", numpy.mean(ratings)
print "average negative score:", numpy.mean(negative_scores)
print "average positive score:", numpy.mean(positive_scores)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: do you need these variables as lists or you want just the mean value?

Comment: if you want to minimize the number of times you traverse `text_collection`, you already have the best solution here

Comment: if you also want to minimize memory requirement, you don't have the optimal solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
scores, ratings = np.array([(t.score, t.rating) for t in text_collection]).T

print 'average score: ', np.mean(scores)
print 'average rating: ', np.mean(ratings)
print 'average positive score: ', np.mean(scores[scores > 0])
print 'average negative score: ', np.mean(scores[scores < 0])
```

EDIT:

To check if there actually are any negative scores, you could so something like this:

```
if np.count_nonzero(scores < 0):
    print 'average negative score: ', np.mean(scores[scores < 0])
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why I'm getting this error for the last line: `average negative score: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:
2374: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return mean(axis, dtype, out)
 nan`

Comment: Yes, that means you have no negative scores and you are indexing the scores array with an empty list (to see what is going on in the last two lines you should lookup numpy's fancy indexing). I'm surprised it doesn't throw a useful exception instead of barfing a nan.

Comment: Great, that fixed it. Thanks for the pointer. Reading about fancy indexing now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind looping for each item you want to get from the collection? marginally less efficient, but much more clear:

```
avg_score = numpy.mean([t.score for t in text_collection])
avg_rating = numpy.mean([t.rating for t in text_collection])
avg_neg_score = numpy.mean([t.rating for t in text_collection if t.score < 0])
avg_pos_score = numpy.mean([t.rating for t in text_collection if t.score > 0])
```

Comment: You don't need the `[` and `]`; it then becomes a generator expression with implied parentheses `(...)` if it's the only argument.

Comment: @ninjagecko: numpy.mean needs a list.

Comment: Ah, apologies; apparently it does ask for an "array_like". Seems like poor programming on numpy's part though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NumPy available, I think that is your best bet.  It does exactly what you want and has a name that self-documents what you are doing.

If you want a pure python solution:

```
def mean(seq):
    i = 0
    sum = 0.0
    for x in seq:
        sum += x
        i += 1
    if i == 0:
        raise ValueError, "cannot take mean of zero-length sequence"
    return sum / i
```

I wrote that to work with any sequence, including things like generator expressions that compute the values.  So it only runs through the sequence once, and it keeps its own counter so it knows how many there were.  If you know for sure you only want to take the mean of a list:

```
def list_mean(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        raise ValueError, "cannot take mean of zero-length list"
    return float(sum(lst)) / len(lst)
```

If you call that on an iterator or generator expression, the `len()` won't work and you will get a `TypeError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the avg_score from avg_neg_score and avg_pos_score with a simple operation:

```
nneg = len(negative_scores)
npos = len(positive_scores)
avg_score = (avg_neg_score * nneg + avg_pos_score * npos) / (nneg + npos)
```

edit: If you are creating the arrays by iterating text_collection, this will be more efficient (assuming you only want the means):

```
n = len(text_collection)
(npos, sumpos) = (0, 0)
(nneg, sumneg) = (0, 0)
sumrating = 0
for t in text_collection:
    sumrating += t.rating
    if t.score < 0:
        sumneg += t.score
        nneg += 1
    else:
        sumpos += t.score
        npos += 1
avg_score = (sumneg + sumpos) / n
avg_neg_score = sumneg / nneg
avg_pos_score = sumpos / npos
avg_rating = sumrating / n
```

edit2: fixed: avg_neg_rating to avg_neg_score...